# Comparing things (eg. as good as)

Tags: anglais, comparatifs

How do you compare things in French?

For example:

> That sandwich was not as good as the last one I had here. (at a restaurant)
>   The bus was not as fast as it normally is, so I got home late.

Answer (score 14):

You'll want to use "pas aussi ... que..." for "not as ... as ...".

> Ce sandwich n'était pas aussi bon que le dernier que j'ai mangé ici.
>
> Le bus n'était pas aussi rapide que d'habitude, et donc je suis arrivé plus tard à la maison.

But that's not really comparing things - in which case you could say:

> Ce sandwich était moins bon que le dernier que j'ai mangé ici (*This sandwich was less good than the last one I ate here*)

And also, if that stupid sandwich was, after all, better:

> Ce sandwich est meilleur que le dernier que j'ai mangé ici. (*This sandwich is better than the last one I had here.*)

Or:

> Cet arbre est plus grand que ma maison. (*This tree is taller than my house.*)

(There is no word for "plus grand" in French)

Answer (score 8):

**The regular comparative:**

- plus+adj+que (more+adj+than)
- aussi+adj+que (as+adj+as)
- moins+adj+que (less+adj+than)

> Le requin est plus gros que les poissons.
>
> Les fraises sont aussi rouges que les fleurs.
>
> La tortue est moins rapide que le lièvre.

**The regular superlative:**

- le/la/les+moins/plus+adj

> La chambre la moins spacieuse.

**The irregular comparative forms:**

- For "mauvais"(bad) the comparative is "plus mauvais" or "pire".
- For "bon"(good) the comparative is "meilleur"
  (for the feminine form we add "e" in the end of meilleur=meilleure)

> Mes problèmes sont pires que les tiens.

**The irregular superlative forms:**

- le plus mauvais / Le pire(s)
- le meilleur(es)

> J'ai passé les pires vacances de ma vie !

Comment: Not `fleures`, but `fleurs`.

Comment: Yes, of course!